# How to check if [dot]folders exist using python

Tags: python, directory, python-os, dotfiles

I'm trying to make a python package and I want to take input from the user and save the info in a `.example` folder in the root directory so that I can access that info later. This is what I implemented but it's not working  -

```
def root_path():
    return os.path.abspath(os.sep)

if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, ".example")):
    #get info
else:
    #create .example in root
```

I want this to work on all operating system (Linux, MacOs and Windows majorly).

Does the `isdir()` function not work with hidden directories? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question. Could you provide any feedback if this was useful?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a path exists or not, you can do this

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists(".hidden-folder")
True
```

Comment: I want to check if the path `/.example` exists from somewhere else like - `/Desktop/Work`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if `.example` is a directory or not by using:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.isdir('.example')
```

It will give you `True` in case `.example` exists and is a directory. Otherwise, it will return `False`.

Comment: I want to check if the path `/.example` exists from somewhere else like - `/Desktop/Work `